# Midnight on Jan 1, 1970 (the Unix epoch) doesn't display as a date in SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

If you select a `date` or `datetime` value that is exactly 1 Jan 1970 at 00:00:00, SEDE displays "0" instead of the date. See [**this query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/269027/sede-epoch-bug) for a repro.

[image]

The second and third column should probably both display "1970-01-01 00:00:00". If you view text-only results, you get "1970-01-01 00:00:00" just fine.

Comment: Um... What are you searching for that you need a date B.S.O.?

Comment: @JonEricson Basically, I was writing a query that looked at data from the past month, from the past year, and from all time. I figured that the Unix epoch was as good a choice of a cutoff for "forever" as anything (`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE CreationDate > @something`), and lo and behold, I ran into this bug.

Comment: I guess 2008-01-01 is enough, since [so] is the oldest site and it seems there is [no question older than that](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4/revisions). Good finding, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really applicable in the context of the available data, but a bug nevertheless…[now squashed](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/60), pending a pull and redeploy.